# Mixing Jar files with different manifest "Permissons"

Tags: java, security, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

Since Oracle's last Java update (1.7.0u45), I've had to try and understand the `Permissions` and similar MANIFEST tags, since they are now required for proper JNLP operation. There's one aspect in particular that I still find a bit of a conundrum.

Particularly, I have a few Jar files that only contain resources ("resource" as in `ClassLoader.getResource`, that is) that I share between a few slightly different programs. As such, I've put them by themselves in an extension JNLP that I link from the various JNLP files for the different programs. These Jar files only contain data files and no class files whatsoever.

Since they contain no code, I figured this JNLP extension shouldn't require any permissions, and therefore I have previously configured it as such, having only an empty `<security />` tag in the JNLP file. Now that the Jar files need their own `Permissions` declaration, I declared them, consequently, as `Permissions: sandbox`.

The weird thing is that as long as I do this, the programs themselves, which require `Permissions: all-permissions`, can't seem to find the resources at all. `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` simply returns `null` as if the files just didn't exist. If I redeclare the resource Jar files with a `Permissions: all-permissions` declaration and also add the corresponding `<all-permissions />` tag to the extension JNLP file, however, it starts working.

This is not actually new with the latest Java update, however. I've got an old Java 1.6 installation lying around as well, and it does the same thing as long as the Jar files have `Permissions` declarations (if I remove the `Permissions` declarations completely, however, it starts working as it always did). This leads me to think that this is intended behavior and defined somewhere in the JNLP specification. However, I can't find anything about it.

I'm a bit disturbed by this "solution" just being guesswork and not knowing if it's even the "right" way to do it. My question, thus, is: Where is this behavior defined? I'd like to read about it authoritatively and understand it properly.

Comment: *"..and understand it properly."* Part of that would be searching the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/) for similar behavior and reporting it as an anomaly if not found.  It does sound like wrong behavior to me.

Comment: Having web start problems myself, I came across this URL.  Maybe it will help you.  Let us know if you get this working!  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html